# Exclude certain requests from Tomcat's log

Tags: tomcat, logging

My Tomcat access log is currently **cluttered with health check requests** from a load balancer, so it's rather hard to actually understand what's going on. For example, using GoAccess I can see some misleading statistics:

```
Hits      h% Vis.    v%   Bandwidth Mtd Proto    Data
 ----- ------ ---- ----- ----------- --- -------- ----
 46221 81.20%    2 0.02%   30.72 MiB GET HTTP/1.1 /geoserver/index.html
 16     0.03%    1 0.01%   50.23 KiB GET HTTP/1.1 /geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/jpeg.
 16     0.03%    1 0.01%  338.80 KiB GET HTTP/1.1 /geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png.
```

The log is created using Tomcat's standard [Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging). The valve is supposed to have a parameter, `conditionUnless`, which I try to use in order to get rid of all those requests being made to `index.html` (that's where health check goes, so I can safely filter out all of them).

According to documentation, `conditionUnless`:

> Turns on conditional logging. If set, requests will be logged only if
>   `ServletRequest.getAttribute()` is `null`. For example, if this value is
>   set to junk, then a particular request will only be logged if
>   `ServletRequest.getAttribute("junk") == null`. The use of Filters is an
>   easy way to set/unset the attribute in the ServletRequest on many
>   different requests.

But I can't figure out how to use Filters to filter out all requests to `index.html`and flag them in some what. Obviously, the following in `server.xml` is not enough:

```
<Valve  className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
        directory="/var/log/tomcat8/accesslogs"
        prefix="node1" suffix=".log"
        pattern="combined"
        renameOnRotate="true"
        conditionUnless="index.html" />
```

**How can I exclude all requests to `index.html`?**

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a [filter as suggested in tomcat group](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-configure-Access-logs-to-ignore-images-td2141292.html) that adds an attribute as **doLog**

```
public final class LoggingFilter implements Filter { 

  private FilterConfig filterConfig = null; 

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
    throws IOException, ServletException { 

    request.setAttribute(filterConfig.getInitParameter("doLog"), "true");         
    chain.doFilter(request, response); 
  } 
  public void destroy() { 
    this.filterConfig = null; 
  } 
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) { 
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;   
  } 
}
```

and then check attribute name using [conditionIf](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging)

```
conditionIf="doLog"
```

> **conditionIf**
>   Turns on conditional logging. If set, requests will be logged only if ServletRequest.getAttribute() is not null. For example, if this value is set to important, then a particular request will only be logged if ServletRequest.getAttribute("important") != null. The use of Filters is an easy way to set/unset the attribute in the ServletRequest on many different requests.

and add filter to web.xml:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>com.yourpackage.LoggingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>logParam</param-name>  
        <param-value>doLog</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/geoserver/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
```

Comment: "> You need to create a filter [...]."
Sure, but how do I do that? The only examples I found regarding filters refer to JSP, while I need to filter a log from GeoServer, which is a WAR deployed in Tomcat, and I have no idea on where to put that JSP file with my filter. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jacob define filter on the path of the jsp

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand. I have no JSP here, only a packaged WAR file that I've deployed on Tomcat.

Comment: @Jacob define filter on the path (url) of the html