# How can I suppress / add condition for access log in Spring Boot (Tomcat)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I enabled access log in my Spring Boot application on the properties file `server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true` but the problem is that now my access log file is bombarded with health check endpoint (provided by spring actuator).

Is there a way to enable access log but filter out the health check ones?

Comment: Maybe this [Filter Access Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714626/how-to-filter-access-logs-generated-by-tomcat-under-spring-boot-framework) will help you.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas I saw the post but it doesn't have any solution either

Comment: @GantengX were you able to solve it ?

Comment: @Dhyey more of a workaround, since I used google stackdriver logging I just do an exclusion that matches the pattern for health check endpoint and it won't be stored there

Answer (score 3):

Finally found out a way.

You need to add a filter and a prop to `application.properties`:

*AccessLogFilter.java*

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/actuator/health")
public class AccessLogFilter implements Filter {

    @Value("${server.tomcat.accesslog.condition-unless}")
    private String conditionUnless;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException

    {
        request.setAttribute(conditionUnless, "NO_LOG");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

*application.properties*

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.condition-unless=accessLog
```

Add `@ServletComponentScan` annotation to main SpringApplication class for `@WebFilter` to work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```