# Filter out TCP requests from tomcat access logs (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am using Spring Boot 3.2.2 with embedded Tomcat 10.1.18, and have enabled Tomcat access logs.

I can filter out HTTP requests from the access logs using a `jakarta.servlet.Filter` as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75595703/12177456

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 @Component
    public class AccessLogFilter implements Filter {
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
                //detect the uri who dontt need to be log 
                if (uri.startsWith("/actuator")) {
                    //add the "No_LOG" Attribute to request, the value is not important, there only need to be not null
                    request.setAttribute("NO_LOG", "true");
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

However, the above filter is only invoked for HTTP requests. I am wondering if there is a way to filter out TCP requests from the log? I have lots of requests like these, which are haproxy health check requests I'd like to exclude:

```
192.123.4.5 - - [21/Feb/2024:10:13:27 +0000] "-" 400 -
```

Comment: What makes you think that is a TCP request? I would filter on the server IP address as the one from HA proxy should be fairly consistent.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum its a TCP request because haproxy is configured to use TCP health checks, and when I disabled the haproxy health checks, the 400 entries went away, and the AccessLogFilter is never invoked for these requests, indicating also that they are not HTTP requests.

Comment: Well those filters are obviously not for TCP requests the are part of the Servlet spec which is HTTP based. The access log is a regular logger, so you might want to configure/wrap the logger in use. Or maybe extend the default `AccessLogValve` of tomcat to provide filtering.